# How to make a UITableView look like this?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I'm curious of how Youtube `s UITableViewCells are done, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Like you can see the cells are like squared and centred, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UICollectionView instead of a UITableView

Cells are automatically centered, just create a square size.

Answer (score 4):

While you actually can use `UICollectionView` instead of a `UITableView`, this layout (YouTube App) can actually be achieved with `UITableView` as well.

You will need to create a custom `UITableViewCell`, that has few images and labels. When you create a custom `UITableViewCell`, you add items to the `contentView` property. You can then change the constraints or frame of the `contentView` property to achieve the effect.

Of course, there are more ways to achieve this layout, but I would follow this one:

1. Create a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`.
2. Give `UITableViewCell` a clear background.
3. Give white background to the `contentView` `UIView` property of the created subclass.
4. Add constraints for margin between cells to `contentView` in `UITableViewCell`.
5. Design the layout of the cell in `contentView`.

It is basically not hard to create a design like this.